# Add 'document_id' column to pandas dataframe of word-id's and wordcounts

Tags: pandas, nltk, word-count

I have following dataset:

```
import pandas as pd
jsonDF = pd.DataFrame({'DOCUMENT_ID':[263403828328665088,264142543883739136], 'MESSAGE':['@Zuora wants to help @Network4Good with Hurric...','@ztrip please help spread the good word on hel...']})

DOCUMENT_ID             MESSAGE
0   263403828328665088  @Zuora wants to help @Network4Good with Hurric...
1   264142543883739136  @ztrip please help spread the good word on hel...
```

I am trying to reshape my data in the form of

```
docID   wordID  count
0   1   118     1
1   1   285     1
2   1   1229    1
3   1   1688    1
4   1   2068    1
```

I used following

```
r=[]
for i in jsonDF['MESSAGE']:
    for j in sortedValues(wordsplit(i)):
        r.append(j)
IDCount_Re=pd.DataFrame(r)
IDCount_Re[:5]
```

gives me following result

```
0               17
1   help         2
2   wants        1
3   hurricane   1
4   relief      1
5   text        1
6   sandy       1
7   donate      1
8              6
9   please    1
```

I can get word counts

I have no idea to to append Document_ID to the in the above dataframe.

Following functions were used to split words

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords 
import re

def wordsplit(wordlist):
    j=wordlist
    j=re.sub(r'\d+', '', j)
    j=re.sub('RT', '',j)
    j=re.sub('http', '', j)
    j = re.sub("(@[A-Za-z0-9]+)|([^0-9A-Za-z \t])|(\w+:\/\/\S+)", " ", j)
    j=j.lower()
    j=j.strip()
    if not j in stopwords.words('english'):
        yield j

def wordSplitCount(wordlist):
    '''merges a list into string, splits it, removes stop words and 
    then counts the occurrences returning an ordered dictitonary'''
    #stopwords=set(stopwords.words('english'))
    string1=''.join(list(itertools.chain(filter(None, wordlist))))
    cnt=Counter()
    j = []
    for i in string1.split(" "):
        i=re.sub(r'&', ' ', i.lower())
        if i not in stopwords.words('english'):
            cnt[i]+=1
    return OrderedDict(cnt)

def sortedValues(wordlist):
    '''creates a dictionary list of occurenced w/ values descending'''
    d=wordSplitCount(wordlist)
    return sorted(d.items(), key=lambda t: t[1], reverse=True)
```

**UPDATE: SOLUTION HERE:**

[string split and and assign unique ids to Pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50012399/string-split-and-and-assign-unique-ids-to-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: You could combine your i,j-loops and inefficient appending in a single generator expression: `wordcounts = Counter(word) for word in sortedValues(wordsplit(msg)) for msg in jsonDF['MESSAGE'])`

Comment: but that does not append DOCUMENT_ID, does it?

Comment: I didn't say it did. I'm suggesting cleaning up your code a bit. Also things like merge your regexes `re.sub(r'(\d+|RT|http)', '', j)`

Comment: Your `sortedValues()` should be replaced with `Counter().most_common()`

Answer (score 0):

'DOCUMENT_ID' is one of the two fields in each row of `jsonDF`. Your current code doesn't access it because it directly works on `jsonDF['MESSAGE']`.

Here is some non-working pseudocode - something like:

```
for _, row in jsonDF.iterrows():
    doc_id, msg = row
    words = [word for word in wordsplit(msg)][0].split() # hack
    wordcounts = Counter(words).most_common() # sort by decr frequency
```

Then do a `pd.concat(pd.DataFrame({'DOCUMENT_ID': doc_id, ...`
and get the 'wordId' and 'count' fields from `wordcounts`.